# trying to hide "download" button once clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple form only consisting of a button that is used to download a file. here is the code :

```
<form method='post' action='download.php?file=file.txt' name='form1'>
<button type='submit'>Telecharger</button>
</form>
```

Download.php is a small php file with header used to engage download, here it is :

```
<?php
    $filename=$_GET['file'];
    header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
    readfile($filename);
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is hide the button or the form after the user clicked on it. So far I have tried toying with css and javascript listener but nothing worked so far.

When I click on the button it download the file but doesn't hide the button.

How can I hide the button after submiting the form ?

Comment: Use Javascript it's the most convenient. Add a `onclick` listener on your button, and then `.hide` it.

Comment: tried it by doing `this.style.display='hidden'` when `onclick` happen. Doesn't work.

Comment: You are doing a php submit. It will not hide your button whatever you do. The page reloads after a php submit. If you wish to hide the button you will have to send ajax call for download

Comment: Validated solution worked fine with the php submit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Javascript:

```
<form method='post' action='download.php?file=file.txt' name='form1'>
  <button onClick='this.style.display = "none";' type='submit'>Telecharger</button>
</form>
```

This will hide your button when it's clicked. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/odjatp2e/) is a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Sth like this?

```js
document.getElementById("downloader").addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style = "display: none;"
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type='submit' id="downloader">Telecharger</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give your button at the very least a class like so,

```
<button class="button-toggle" type='submit'>Telecharger</button>
```

and you can use vanilla js to select and hide it,

```
document.getElementByClassName("test").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    event.target.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }, false);
```

or if you're using jQuery

```
$('.button-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Should get you close.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
<form method='post' action="javascript:alert('Hello there, I am being submitted');" name='form1' id="form">
    <button type='submit' id="hide">Telecharger</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

var button = document.getElementById("hide");

button.addEventListener("click", function(event){   
    button.style.display = "none";
});

</script>
```

I changed the action of the form just to check what was happening, but you can replace that with your action path.